# Are there any hidden downsides to wrapping an Akka ActorRef in a thin wrapper class?

Tags: scala, akka

Being one for strong-typing and letting the compiler do the work (rather than "hoping" I remember), I'd like to use types other than just ActorRef for my akka-based library.

Is there any sort of penalty for doing this? Basically, the wrapper would just implement the same methods (tell, ask, etc...) and just forward it directly to the actor and hold the ActorRef so I can have a strongly-typed facade.

If anyone has any insights that would be great. I'm not familiar enough concurrent programming or the actors model to know if this is going to somehow slow things down.

Edit: Here's some code samples as requested below.

For example. Normally I'd do this in Akka.

```
val actor = context.actorOf(Props[Whatever])
```

At this point, it is typed as an ActorRef. And so everything in my code has to work with ActorRefs. Is there any downside to doing the following instead...

```
class Wrapper(props: Props)(implicit context: ActorContext) {
  val actor = context.actorOf(props)

  def ! (message: Any):Unit = {
    actor ! message
  }

  //insert a direct wrapper of other regular actor functions here.

}
```

Then, it would be called and behave exactly like an actor except I could strongly-type my design. Because each Wrapper would be typed with the enclosing class.

Does this have any downsides? I realize it isn't strictly necessary but leaving behind strong-typing is a bit bothersome.

For me, what came to mind is if this class is going to be running on some set thread and keep the akka actors underneath from behaving as asynchronously as they normally would (swapping out with many sharing a thread pool and so on)... as I am assuming that behavior only occurs for actors and so my class may be setting somewhere else and bottlenecking things.

Comment: I'd like to see a more detailed explication (code) of your concept. I suspect it's not really workable, at least not beyond very simple and highly restrictive cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at [Typed Actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/typed-actors.html).

Comment: Or typed channels - http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/typed-channels.html